# Error with dlopen

Tags: python, macos, dylib, dlopen

i'm loading dynamic lib (in python via ctypes) and get such error:

> OSError: dlopen(mlib.dylib, 6): Symbol not found: _NSLocalizedDescriptionKey
>
> Referenced from: /Users/abc/work/as/mlib.dylib
>
> Expected in: flat namespace
> in /Users/abc/work/as/mlib.dylib

Do you have and idea how can i fix it? I suppose that some libs should be linked to, but which?..

Answer (score 0):

When linking, appropriate framework should be linked, "-framework Foundation" in this case.